# Uploading Page Blob to Azure getting Error: Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using Microsoft Azure Java SDK for Uploading Page Blobs (Size: 20G/40G). IN mid of Uploading, SDK throws Storage Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: null
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.initIOException(Utility.java:584) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStream$2.call(BlobOutputStream.java:414) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStream$2.call(BlobOutputStream.java:398) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:162) ~[azure-storage-1.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:306) ~[azure-storage-1.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:178) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudPageBlob.putPagesInternal(CloudPageBlob.java:642) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudPageBlob.uploadPages(CloudPageBlob.java:971) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStream$2.call(BlobOutputStream.java:402) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

SDK Version:

```
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
<version>1.2.0</version>
```

Please note this error shows up in the mid of Upload randomly:
Transferred bytes: 27325890560 out of total 42949673472

Is there a chance of time drift on a Linux Box causing this issue ? Any other pointers would help.

Code snippet invoking Azure Java SDK API to upload page blob:

```
String storageAccntName = "storageAccount";

URI blobEndpoint = null;
String uriString = "http://" + storageAccntName + ".blob.core.windows.net";
blobEndpoint = new URI(uriString);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(blobEndpoint, new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(storageAccntName, blobInfo.getAccessKey()));
blobClient.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.SHAREDKEYFULL);
blobClient.getDefaultRequestOptions().setRetryPolicyFactory(new RetryLinearRetry());

//Create Storage Container
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(Constants.STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME);
container.createIfNotExists();

//Creating Page Blob corresponding to each disk
CloudPageBlob pageBlob = container.getPageBlobReference("pageBlobName");
File vhdFile  = new File("pageBlobName");
if(vhdFile.length()==0) {
    throw new CPMException("Invalid file with length 0. Stopping upload for file with path: " + vhdFile.getAbsolutePath()
            + " and file name: " + diskBlob.getLocation());
}
LOG.debug("Blob size for Disk: " + diskBlob.getName() + " is: " + vhdFile.length());

pageBlob.create(vhdFile.length());
blobClient.getDefaultRequestOptions().setConcurrentRequestCount(Constants.MAX_CONSUMER_THREADS);
pageBlob.upload(new FileInputStream(vhdFile), vhdFile.length());
```

Comment: Couple of follow up questions: Is this a consistent repro or does this only happen on occasion or once? What Linux distro are you running on and with what version of the JDK?

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft This is not consistent, observed only one one client setup.

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft This is not consistent, observed only one one client setup. Linux distro: RHEL Server release 5.7 (Tikanga). JDK 1.7. We suspect this has something to do with time drift on Linux Box. Is there a way I can confirm that ? What would be resolution for the same ?

Comment: kriti, this seems odd. Since it is happening only on that client, it seems there is something odd about that machine. Can you check the time on that to another source with properly synced time (or just bing "Current Time" to get the time from bing). Also, to troubleshoot, you can also use Storage Logging to see what the server was seeing - details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh343262.aspx

Comment: @AtulSikaria-MSFT Thanks for the reply Atul, already following up on the support case with MSFT Azure, as per their investigation these logs would not be captured in Storage Analytics Logging. This would hit front end and get the failure. Just wanted to widen the scope by posting here if anyone else had hit this.  Would close this thread if I get a resolution, hopefully. Checked time, that is set, NTP is configured. So even if clock has a drift it should recover.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you are using Shared Access Signature to upload the files, and the validity period of the SAS has expired. Based on your blob size, this upload wold get split into multiple requests, and by the time the later requests are made, the SAS may have expired.

If you are using storage account and key rather than SAS, then please paste the snippet of code that is encountering this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Atul. We are using Azure Java SDK for Uploading Page blobs,  internally it might be using SAS but I am not very sure. I added the snippet of code which is invoking Upload API in query above. Also, it is not happening always. Its only on a Customer set up that we are facing this issue. Please let me know if you are looking for something else.